# Using the same variable within str_detect and mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a variable `time_col` which contains the word 'minutes' if it is in minutes (e.g. 20 minutes), and only contains a number if it in hours (e.g. 2). I want to remove the word 'minutes' and convert it into hours when the observation is in minutes.

```
df <- raw_df %>%
      mutate(time_col = ifelse(str_detect(time_col, "minutes"), time_col/60, time_col))
```

However, this gives an error:

> 'Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `time_col`. x non-numeric
> argument to binary operator.'

I don't have this issue when I use `ifelse(str_detect(time_col, "minutes"), 1, 0)` so I think this is because the `str_detect` replaces `time_col` before going over to the `ifelse` condition.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a dummy dataframe to demonstrate.

Since your `time_col` is character, you'll need to first get rid of the string " minutes" (note the space before "minutes"), change it to numeric, then divide it by 60.

### Input

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Dummy = letters[1:3], 
                 time_col = c("2", "20 minutes", "30 minutes"))

df
  Dummy   time_col
1     a          2
2     b 20 minutes
3     c 30 minutes
```

### Code and output

```
df %>% mutate(time_col = ifelse(
  str_detect(time_col, "minutes"),
  as.numeric(gsub(" minutes", "", time_col)) / 60,
  time_col
))

  Dummy          time_col
1     a                 2
2     b 0.333333333333333
3     c               0.5
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I apply this for multiple columns? I've tried `df %>% mutate(across(c('time_col', 'time_col2'), ifelse(
  str_detect(x, "minutes"),
  as.numeric(gsub(" minutes", "", x)) / 60,
  x
))`

Comment: There are a few things you need to note in your `across`. First of all, we don't need quotes `''` for column names. Second, use `~ifelse()`, since we are using a function here. Third, use `.x` instead of `x`, this syntax tells the function we are taking vectors from the dataframe.